# What's the difference between the two expressions?

Tags: java, annotations

```
public @PostConstruct void init()
```

and

```
@PostConstruct
public void init()
```

What's the difference between them in java? It seems that the generated bytecode is identical.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: readability, for one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It seems that the generated bytecode is identical.

Then you got your answer. Semantically, the two constructs will result in the exact same behavior at runtime.

So the only thing left: what does it do "to the source code"? And there it is pure **style**. And to style questions, there are two simple rules to follow:

- Pick the style that works best for you/your team/your product, so do what will be the least surprising for the other people reading this code
- But then, when there isn't much precedence in your group, then you follow the informal conventions of Java.

Regarding that 2nd point, I have never seen a method annotation written down like in your option 1. "The whole world" will write the annotations before the actual signature line.